# View Source in browser not giving all the content which is loaded in browser

Tags: browser, view-source

1) I opened a link in the browser. (suppose My Facebook FriendsList)

2) On Seeing the View Source for the Page. (I can see that around 20 names come in view source - first loaded )

3) Even if I Scroll down and get all the friends list loaded and check the View Source it is giving me same 20 people i.e. no change in the View source even if the page has more content than previous.

4) It may be Ajax request or may be Javascript but how can I get the full source code for the page.

Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: You can not. The data is loaded dynamically when you are on the site and you are scrolling some widget. If you need to get data from facebook you need to use the facebook API

Comment: Even using the Facebook API - I am not able to get the completed Friends List - It only gives me few saying Only these people have registered your apps. I am using User Access Token

Answer (score 0):

In case where dynamic data is to be analysed , Developer tools of browsers comes handy.

Use Chrome developer tool. (Simply right click on any dynamic page and click Inspect)

Edit: For Dynamic Page Scrapping ,Use PhantomJS with NodeJs and Than import into your python script.

Comment: Want to get it using python?